# Undo settings changes for git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always

Tags: git

I am learning how to work with pull requests in a team environment.  This is a setting I configured, but am not sure it is the best way to go about it.  How can I cancel / change it?

Answer (score 4):

While the answers given are correct that you can simply edit your `.gitconfig` file to remove the setting manually, it's also possible to remove a setting via the command line.

`git config` offers a `--unset` option which, as the name suggests, *unsets* a setting to its initial value. [Take a look at the documentation.](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)

In your case such a command could look like this:

```
git config --global --unset branch.autosetuprebase
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the config in a couple of places. It depends if you set up that config as a repo or global config. See [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set this up with the `--global` flag, these will go to your user level `gitconfig` file. In case of linux, this would mean you would have this set in your `~/.gitconfig` file.

To remove it, simply open your `~/.gitconfig` file and remove the following entry from under `[branch]` heading

```
[branch]
    autosetuprebase = always
```